# Nginx Proxy Pass Rewrite URI from path

Tags: nginx

I'm dealing with this:

I need to proxy https://localhost.com/1045/file.txt to https://1045.external.com/file.txt

Tried this:

```
location ~* ^/([^/]+) 
          {
                 proxy_pass $scheme://$1.external.com/file.txt;
          }
```

This redirect to https://1045.external.com/1045/file.txt and return me 404 Not Found.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a [regular expression server_name directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) to capture any part of the requested hostname.

Comment: I just change the question since I can edit the request... do you know how to rewrite uri before the proxy_pass ??